# Is there a way to reboot a Windows Docker container?

Tags: docker, azure-service-fabric, docker-for-windows, service-fabric-on-premises

I know this defeats the point of containers, but does anyone know if there is a way to successfully reboot a Windows Docker container? I need to do this as we need to install "ServiceFabric Runtime" & "ServiceFabric SDK" onto our Azure DevOps build agents both of which require a reboot due to dependencies.

I managed to install both of these packages onto the container and I was able to run ServiceFabric commands successfully but as the container hasn't been rebooted "Azure DevOps" doesn't think the software is installed. If you run `Get-WmiObject win32_product` both of the ServiceFabric packages do not show as installed.

Comment: Have you try   `docker restart <<container>> `?

Comment: I have, didn't seem to do much. I think it restarted the last known layer rather than a full restart of the OS.

Comment: A very similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39715448/5946937)